# Having Issue On Bootstrap Multi Dropdown Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/N533jxntvM) and let me know how to fix the code  below to First slide Up any drop down and then animate slide down? Right now what is happening is conflicts between clicks on third `Dropdown`!
If you click on third dropdown it slide down the third menu before sliding up the second open menu bar!

```
$(function(){
 $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
  });
  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(400, function(){
        $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
        $('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded','false');
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this code:

```
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
  });

  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
  });
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/hL3Zx6ISXh)

Comment: Hi Sirwan Afifi, Thanks for reply but this is causing another issue on Mobile Screen! the menu appears and disappear on closing !